# Step by step guide about how to make Apache Tomcat work with Ruby on Rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tomcat, installation, documentation

I have Windows 7 x64. Both Tomcat and Rails are installed and working. I just do not know how to make them work together.

Therefor I am looking for a link to a step by step guide about how to make Apache Tomcat work with Ruby on Rails application. Suggestions?

Comment: I'm voting to delete this question because I wasn't aware of technologies at that time and mixed them up in this question. It is misleading other StackOverflow users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tomcat is for Java applications, which allows you to run Java Servlet and JavaServer Pages. You do not need a full Apache Tomcat server, a normal Apache or Nginx webserver is enough. With the help of [Phusion Passenger](http://www.modrails.com/), deployment of Rails applications is really easy. Just follow the [Phusion Passenger users guide](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html). If you must use Tomcat, though, you can [connect the Apache Tomcat server with an Apache web server](http://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/). This requires [the mod_jk module](http://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/webserver_howto/apache.html), a Tomcat-Apache plug-in that handles the communication between Tomcat and Apache.

Comment: Passenger does not support Windows: http://forums.pragprog.com/forums/148/topics/9870

Answer (score 2):

One way is to use JRuby as your Ruby interpreter, http://jruby.org. Then you can call java libraries from Ruby, develop using WEBrick, and deploy by turning your Rails app into a war file using the warble gem, http://rubygems.org/gems/warbler. The war file can of course then be deployed using Tomcat or JBoss, as easily as dropping it into Tomcat's web-apps directory.

You could also look at TorqueBox http://torquebox.org/ for a way to deploy Rails apps on JRuby and JBoss.

Comment: I don't want to move back to JRuby again.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you have tomcat running on port 8080? If so, you will want to setup a proxy to have tomcat. If you could be more specific as to what you mean by work together that would help. Here is a link to how to proxy tomcat.

http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/proxy-howto.html